# Microsoft push notification service pricing

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone, mpns

I've read Microsoft documentation about Push Notification Service that they are offering for Windows phones but there is no information about pricing. I've read somewhere that it is free to use max 500 notification per day/per application/per device and it is unauthenticated mode but there is also authenticated mode which has no daily limit and cost some money. Is that true and if it is, how much is price?

Also I am interested in information about saving messages in server if user is not active in time of sending. How much push messages can Microsoft Push Service save for one device/user before starts to discard it?

Answer (score 1):

It is free, authenticated or not.

Not sure if they actually store messages on the server to be delivered. When you send one they will give you the clients connection status as part of the response.

Comment: In one blog Microsoft employee Yochay Kiriaty said this (in blog comments):                                                         Q: Is there any Fee for using MPNS

A: In short the answer is yes and no. There is no charge for up to 500 messages per 24 hr per URI. Back to answer #2, that mean you can send (between your back-end and MPNS ) up to 500 messages. With that said, if you need to go above 500 messages per URI (per app per device per 24 hours) then you can opt-in to the throttle mode which as indicated in answer #1, you can go beyond 500 messages and use secure channel

Comment: this is the blog : http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/05/04/understanding-how-microsoft-push-notification-works-part-2.aspx

Comment: If you're sending more than 500 messages in 24 hours to a single device, you may want to reconsider your practices anyway ;) I doubt very many programs would have a good reason for exceeding this limit.  In any case, like the comments above, if you do exceed the limit of 500 per 24 hour period, per registration channel (effectively per device), then you can opt in to the throttle mode.  Either way, it's free.